# Firebase error: symbolFileMappings:upsert: The uploaded file is not a valid Breakpad Symbol file

Tags: firebase, crash-reports, firebase-crash-reporting, dsym

I am trying to upload a dSYM file to Firebase using this command:

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload -i ./Info.plist -p ./GoogleService-Info.plist ./service-accounts/mtb.json 78*****C-5**4-3***-***C-00*********7
```

But each time I run this, I get back the following errors

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash:377: error: symbolFileMappings:upsert: The uploaded file is not a valid Breakpad Symbol file.
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash:378: note: symbolFileMappings:upsert: The metadata for the symbol file failed to update.
```

I have tried this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/4829Sp1_uKY/IEC_T4-VBAAJ but haven't had any luck as it errors out to

```
usage: batch-upload [-hv] [-p google-service] [-i info] service-account-file {mach-o file|uuid}
```

Can someone help me on this one please?

Thanks

Comment: same here. couldn't find a solution yet

Comment: Did you have the latest Pods version ?

Comment: @Ludovic yes I have

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this bug relates to batch-upload script having problems with archives, so you would need to patch it manually.

Try the following:

- Change `extract_symbols_and_upload "$EXE" "$ARCH" "$BUNDLE"` to
  `extract_symbols_and_upload "$EXE" "$ARCH" "$BUNDLE/$BNDL_PATH"`

> *The dump_syms utility understands dSYM bundles but not archives,
>   curiously enough. This fix will go out with the next release.*

**[Source](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-talk/16681sc5qj/firebase-problems-with-firebasecrash-symbol-upload)**